# Recommended techniques for changing the appearance/design of my Bootstrap sub-theme?

Tags: 7, theming

I use [Bootstrap (7.x-3.0](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) for Drupal 7 which I already [created my own sub-theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010) and I enabled this sub-theme as my default theme. It seems to work so far.

Now, I want to change the appearance/design of my menu. Here is the appearance with the Bartik-theme:

[image]

And here is the equivalent using the Bootstrap-theme:

[image]

If I want to customize the Bootstrap theme to look similar to the Bartik theme, how do I do this? In the base-theme folder of Bootstrap I found *menu-tree.func* where the menu tags are generated, which looks like so:

```
/**
 * @file
 * menu-tree.func.php
 */

/**
 * Overrides theme_menu_tree().
 */
function bootstrap_menu_tree(&$variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu nav">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

/**
 * Bootstrap theme wrapper function for the primary menu links.
 */
function bootstrap_menu_tree__primary(&$variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}

/**
 * Bootstrap theme wrapper function for the secondary menu links.
 */
function bootstrap_menu_tree__secondary(&$variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu nav navbar-nav secondary">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

Do I have to edit this file? I don't really think so. Further, each element of the menu uses the class called *leaf* which I couldn't find at all in any files of Bootstrap.

Hope my point is clear. I just want to edit the appearance of my menu and also of further elements without creating an entire `custom-node.tpl.php`. Is that possible or do I have to create an entire new file?

Comment: you don't need to change into base theme, just edit or add anything into your newly created sub theme freely.

Comment: But where do I edit my existing menu? Which is the file I need to edit?

Comment: So, you mean I should add a new node-custom.tpl.php, right?

Comment: You should be able to all this with CSS and not need to mess with custom template files.

Comment: This guide will help you understand theming in Drupal : http://themery.com/dgd7. In particular you might want to read about theme functions and preprocessors. Otherwise I'm not sure anything we suggest will make any sense.

Comment: Thank you. I will also have a look at the guide but I've started to create template files. Seems to be nice so far :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Bootstrap as a style framework already, I'd recommend you simply restyle the navbar to look like Bartik. You'll have to modify your `page.tpl.php` template to move the various elements of the header around to put the site title and user menu on top of the main menu.

Comment: That's what I did. I've started to create my own templates. Thx.